# NSHost run in device gives an NSHost.h error

Tags: ios, iphone, nshost

NSHost doesnot support to iphone... When I run this in simulator it works fine... But when I want to run in device means it gives an NSHost.h error....

I want to do this in device also.
How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

NSHost is a private API on the iPhone and is thus not supported on the actual device.

Answer (score 1):

Apple have published a technical note (QA1652) on "[Using NSStreams For A TCP Connection Without NSHost](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1652/_index.html)."

There's a code sample on that page, but here's a summary:

> You can do this by exploiting the
>   toll-free bridge between NSStream and
>   CFStream. Use
>   CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost to
>   create CFStreams to the host, and then
>   cast the resulting CFStreams to
>   NSStreams.