# Why does code that uses NSHost compile correctly using the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nshost

I have some code that was written for Mac OS X and it makes a lot of use of the `NSHost` class. During my efforts to bring this code to the iPhone, I discovered that `NSHost` isn't available in the iPhone SDK, and should instead be replaced with `NSStream` and the related networking classes.

Anywho, I've been working on it to port it over to the iPhone and I noticed that even without removing the `NSHost` code, it still compiles without any errors. This is compiling against the device SDK (not simulator). Surely if the class isn't in the iPhone SDK it should give me a compile error saying it couldn't find the symbols or something?

Could it be that `NSHost` **is** available on the iPhone, but made private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks like it's private API but still available.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006754/nshost-problem) Still, it should give you some compiler warnings. Have you tried cleaning the build?

Comment: Hm, thought so. Cleaning the build doesn't make a difference. I'll still be porting it over to use NSStream, not going to be using private APIs.